# Grails war fails to deploy java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError and SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings

Tags: tomcat, grails, groovy, war, slf4j

My application works fine when i use grails `run-app` but when a try to run using the war file with `run-war` i get the following errors:

I already tried some solutions proposed here on stack but none of them solved the problem.

and the package/class that are being showed on the trace are from one of my domain classes :

> nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gneellaan/Ecf

`gneellaan` = `package` and `Ecf` = `domain class`

```
|Running Grails application
Error |
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
Error |
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/grails-2.4.2/dist/grails-plugin-log4j-2.4.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
Error |
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Grails/gneellaan/target/work/tomcat/webapps/gneellaan/WEB-INF/lib/grails-plugin-log4j-2.4.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
Error |
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
Error |
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory]
2014-10-23 14:28:08,255 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gneellaan/Ecf
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gneellaan/Ecf
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gneellaan.Ecf
    ... 5 more
2014-10-23 14:28:08,257 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gneellaan/Ecf
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gneellaan/Ecf
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gneellaan/Ecf
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gneellaan.Ecf
    ... 5 more
2014-10-23 14:28:08,258 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing Grails: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gneellaan/Ecf
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gneellaan/Ecf
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gneellaan/Ecf
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gneellaan.Ecf
    ... 5 more
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gneellaan/Ecf
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gneellaan/Ecf
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gneellaan.Ecf
    ... 5 more
Error listenerStart
Context [/gneellaan] startup failed due to previous errors
The web application [/gneellaan] registered the JDBC driver [org.h2.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
The web application [/gneellaan] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
The web application [/gneellaan] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
|Server running. Browse to http://localhost:9091/gneellaan
|Server running. Browse to http://localhost:9091/gneellaan
```

Answer (score 1):

Right - its' a classpath problem, and the Slf4j messages are ignorable warnings. There's a big difference between `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` and `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. `ClassNotFoundException` by itself is easy - there's no jar file or directory in the classpath containing that class or resource. Fix the classpath, or add the missing library to it, and move on.

But `NoClassDefFoundError` (which will cause a `ClassNotFoundException`) is a lot harder to fix. It indicates that the named class was found but when loading it, a dependency that it has wasn't met. This should be relatively rare when using Grails, Maven, Gradle, etc. which integrate dependency management, and determine what the dependencies of your dependencies are and include those. But when we configure the lookup to not recurse through the dependency graph, or exclude one or more jars that we think are safe to exclude, this can happen.

I'm guessing that `gneellaan.Ecf` is your class - there's exactly 1 result for that in Google, and it's this question (it's technically two words, but I'm still calling it a Googlewhack). If it was a 3rd-party library, you could use a site like http://mvnrepository.com/ to determine dependencies (e.g. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.hawt/hawtio-util/1.4.27). But you have the source, so it shouldn't be too hard to find the cause. If there's a lot going on in that class, try commenting out what you can , Make sure everyting still compiles, but remove what you can.